# method_missing gotchas in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Are there any things to be careful about when defining the `method_missing` method in Ruby?  I'm wondering whether there are some not-so-obvious interactions from inheritance, exception throwing, performance, or anything else.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

A somewhat obvious one: always redefine `respond_to?` if you redefine `method_missing`.  If `method_missing(:sym)` works, `respond_to?(:sym)` should always return true.  There are many libraries that rely on this.

*Later:*

An example:

```
# Wrap a Foo; don't expose the internal guts.
# Pass any method that starts with 'a' on to the
# Foo.
class FooWrapper
  def initialize(foo)
    @foo = foo
  end
  def some_method_that_doesnt_start_with_a
    'bar'
  end
  def a_method_that_does_start_with_a
    'baz'
  end
  def respond_to?(sym, include_private = false)
    pass_sym_to_foo?(sym) || super(sym, include_private)
  end
  def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
    return foo.call(sym, *args, &block) if pass_sym_to_foo?(sym)
    super(sym, *args, &block)
  end
  private
  def pass_sym_to_foo?(sym)
    sym.to_s =~ /^a/ && @foo.respond_to?(sym)
  end
end

class Foo
  def argh
    'argh'
  end
  def blech
    'blech'
  end
end

w = FooWrapper.new(Foo.new)

w.respond_to?(:some_method_that_doesnt_start_with_a)
# => true
w.some_method_that_doesnt_start_with_a
# => 'bar'

w.respond_to?(:a_method_that_does_start_with_a)
# => true
w.a_method_that_does_start_with_a
# => 'baz'

w.respond_to?(:argh)
# => true
w.argh
# => 'argh'

w.respond_to?(:blech)
# => false
w.blech
# NoMethodError

w.respond_to?(:glem!)
# => false
w.glem!
# NoMethodError

w.respond_to?(:apples?)
w.apples?
# NoMethodError
```

Comment: That's interesting. How would you implement that for a class which consists of "normal" methods and "dynamic" methods (implemented via method_missing)?

Comment: @Christoph: Your `pass_sym_to_foo?` method becomes a generic `handle?` method which decides whether to try to process this request or hand it off to `super`'s `method_missing`.

Comment: In Ruby 1.9.2, it's even better to redefine `respond_to_missing?`, see my blog post: http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2010/11/methodmissing-politely.html

Comment: A few corrections should be made here:
1) `respond_to?` actually takes two arguments. Failing to specify the second argument can cause subtle argument errors (see http://technicalpickles.com/posts/using-method_missing-and-respond_to-to-create-dynamic-methods/)
2) You do not need to pass arguments to super in this case. `super` implicitly calls the superclass method with the original arguments

Answer (score 13):

If your method missing method is only looking for certain method names, don't forget to call super if you haven't found what you're looking for, so that other method missings can do their thing.

Comment: Yes - otherwise your method call will silently fail and you'll spend hours trying to figure out why your method isn't working even though there are no errors.  (not that I would have done such a thing)

Answer (score 11):

If you can anticipate method names, it is better to dynamically declare them than to rely on method_missing because method_missing incurs a performance penalty.  For example, suppose you wanted to extend a database handle to be able to access database views with this syntax:

```
selected_view_rows = @dbh.viewname( :column => value, ... )
```

Rather than relying on method_missing on the database handle and dispatching the method name to the database as the name of a view, you could determine all the views in the database ahead of time, then iterate over them to create "viewname" methods on @dbh.

Answer (score 6):

Building on [Pistos's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291132/methodmissing-gotchas-in-ruby#292838): `method_missing` is at least an order of magnitude slower than regular method calling on all the Ruby implementations I've tried.  He is right to anticipate when possible to avoid calls to `method_missing`.

If you're feeling adventurous, check out Ruby's little-known [Delegator](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/index.html) class.

Answer (score 3):

James' answer is great but, in modern ruby (1.9+), like  Marc-André is saying, you want to redefine `respond_to_missing?` because it gives you access to other methods on top of `respond_to?`, like `method(:method_name)`returning the method itself.

Example, the defined following class:

```rb
class UserWrapper
  def initialize
    @json_user = { first_name: 'Jean', last_name: 'Dupont' }
  end

  def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
    return @json_user[sym] if @json_user.keys.include?(sym)
    super
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(sym, include_private = false)
    @json_user.keys.include?(sym) || super
  end
end
```

Results in:

```
irb(main):015:0> u = UserWrapper.new
=> #<UserWrapper:0x00007fac7b0d3c28 @json_user={:first_name=>"Jean", :last_name=>"Dupont"}>
irb(main):016:0> u.first_name
=> "Jean"
irb(main):017:0> u.respond_to?(:first_name)
=> true
irb(main):018:0> u.method(:first_name)
=> #<Method: UserWrapper#first_name>
irb(main):019:0> u.foo
NoMethodError (undefined method `foo' for #<UserWrapper:0x00007fac7b0d3c28>)
```

So, always define `respond_to_missing?` when overriding `method_missing`.

Answer (score 1):

Another gotcha:

`method_missing` behaves differently between `obj.call_method` and `obj.send(:call_method)`. Essentially the former one miss all private and non-defined methods, while later one doesn't miss private methods.

So you `method_missing` will never trap the call when someone calling your private method via `send`.